# How to write efficient Jquery event Listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project where I have a ton of checkboxes. When checked, these checkboxes "unhide" a Div in the dashboard. Then, a span element gets appended to the unhidden div. There is also a cleanUp() function which takes care of the element clean up when a change occurs in the dashbaord. There is a putOverlay() function which takes care of the overlays that have to be shown. Now with about 400 checkboxes which Hide/Show one of the appropriate divs in the dashboard . My function looks something like this.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#sel,.show-item").on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function() {
                console.log("Im trying");
                var checked = $(this).attr('id');
                console.log(checked);
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $("#stickyFilters").show();
                    $('#taxIA').show();
                    $('#taxIA').append('<p id="' + checked + '" class="remove" style="display:inline; float:left"><span id="' + checked + '">' + checked + '<input type="button" value="X"></input></span></p>');
                    putOverlay();
                } else {
                    $('#taxIA span[id^="' + checked + '"]').remove();
                    cleanUp();
                    putOverlay();
                }
            });
        });
```

Now an issue is that with so many checkboxes, I am having to repeat myself and it certainly is not the most efficient way of writing JQuery. I am not regarding the principles of good code. So my code is "WET" (Write Everything Twice).

I have tried wrapping the 2 changing parts of the function which are the checkbox listener and the corresponding div in an object and to create a dynamic listener for checkbox change events. But this does not seem to be an approach that would work. Any suggestions on how I could not repeat myself and write more efficient Jquery? Any help is appreciated.

Here is an example of the checkbox set up in the application.

Checkbox Section :

```
 <div id="collapseMain" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <!-- Differed Panel Group 2  -->
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="invertebrateAnimals" id="invertebrateAnimals"></input>&nbsp;
                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" id="invertebrateAnimals">
                                Invertebrate Animals
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body" id="selectionInvertebrateAnimals" class="selectionInvertebrateAnimals">
                            <p id="sel">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Arachnida (Spiders, Mites, Ticks, Scorpions, and relatives)">&nbsp;&nbsp;Arachnida (Spiders, Mites, Ticks, Scorpions, and relatives)
                                </input><br>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Bivalvia (Mussels and Clams)">&nbsp;&nbsp;Bivalvia (Mussels and Clams)</input><br>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Branchiopoda (Fairy Shrimp, Clam Shrimp, Water Fleas, and Tadpole Shrimp)">&nbsp;&nbsp;Branchiopoda (Fairy Shrimp, Clam Shrimp, Water Fleas, and Tadpole Shrimp)
                                </input><br>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Clitellata (Leeches)">&nbsp;&nbsp;Clitellata (Leeches)
                                </input><br>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Dashboard Section which has DIVs that hide and unhide by event listeners action:

```
<div class="col-sm-9" id="showHide">
        <div id="stickyFilters" class="wrapper" style="background-color : #ced4c4;" data-step="9" data-intro='<p class="italic">Dashboard</p><br>The dashboard area shows you, at a glance, which filters you currently have set. You can click the red "X" next to a filter to remove it.'>
            <div class="row" id="rowA" style="width: auto;">
                <div class="majorTaxGroup">
                    <div id="taxIA" class="dashBoard"><b>Invertebrate Animals : </b></div>
                    <div id="taxVP" class="dashBoard"><b>Vascular Plants : </b></div>
                    <div id="taxVA" class="dashBoard"><b>Vertebrate Animals : </b></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

A change in the checkbox Section section triggers the event and then talks to the Dashboard Section appropriately. 
Also,I wrote an event that tracks any change in the DOM with the DOM bind event if content changes. This specifically does not do anything except console.log() that something changed in the dashboard Section.

```
$('#stickyFilters').bind('contentchanged', function() {
    console.log('CHANGED SOMETHING IN THE STICKYFILTERS!!!!');
});
```

Comment: I'm sure you can DRY this up. The general approach is to use DOM traversal methods instead of specifically targeting related elements by `id`. If you want a specific example of this we would need to see your HTML and any related CSS. Note that a cut down example is fine, ie. just 2 or 3 checkboxes and related elements instead of the full 400

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Just made an update to the HTML Section. Thanks!